# Extract Knowledge from RandomForest (scikit-learn)

Tags: scikit-learn, random-forest

i am using a RandomForest classifier and after having trained and tested the model
i would like to extract "some Knowledge" from it. I know that a RandomForest combine 
the votes of a number of trees...but is there a way to extract the interpretation rules
of each tree???.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to extract knowledge directly from the trees because the classification is made by a majority vote. Decision rules would be too hard to analyse.

Instead, you can analyse how important is each variable in the final classification model.
You should have a look at the `feature_importances_` attribute of `RandomForestClassifier`.

I also suggest you to read the original Random Forest paper to get further information about this variable importance measure.

```
Breiman, Leo. "Random forests." Machine learning 45.1 (2001): 5-32.
```